# MySQL: Show latest occurence of a field in a grouped row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a `item` table and an `order` one. I am showing latest ordered items grouped by name, cost and currency, so that I can show how many times has a product been ordered. I use this query:

```
SELECT  o.id AS orderId, COUNT(i.id) AS countItems, i.id AS prodId, item_name, cost, currency
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN order AS o
ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, REPLACE(o.items, ' ', ''))
GROUP BY item_name, cost, currency
ORDER BY orderId DESC
```

(the `FIND_IN_SET` is needed because the items of an order are kept comma-separated in a field in `order` table)

If in one result the item can be grouped (`countItems >= 2`), its `orderId` will always show the first order ID, not the latest (e.g., if an item has same name, cost and currency in order 120 and order 230, the result will show `orderId` 120).

**Is there a way to make `orderId` show the latest order instead of the first one?**

**UPDATE**:

As per this [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/186ec2/1), I would like the resulting row to show `ordId` 826 instead of 693.

Comment: Any sample and desired dataset with table definitions ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't show the first one, it shows an arbitrary one. Please take my advice and don't use separated lists to hold the items of an order. That's bad table design. To find the highest orderID use a correlated subquery.

Comment: @VMai I know separated lists are a bad practice, but this was done by someone else before me and can't change it now.

Comment: post some sample data and we can answer it.. i have a few ideas, but i want to try it first

Comment: You can find your answer in this excellent manual entry: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @fancyPants thanks for pointing out. If you write it as an answer (and put a lil' example ;) I'll tick it as chosen answer.